# MySQL : Select data from cloud database, and insert onto localhost database?

Tags: mysql, database, insert, localhost

I am looking to run a query on a cloud MySQL instance and then insert into my local database instance. I am not able to find how to accurately reference the localhost in the query. Here is what I am looking for:

```sql
INSERT INTO localhost:'port'.'local table'
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    'cloud table'
```

Comment: corrected syntax highlightning

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in a query.  You can move data between databases on the same host but not different hosts. There are number of ways you could do this...just not the way you suggested.

Your best option, if you don't mind locking the tables, is to just dump the table you want from your cloud DB and import it onto your localhost. Or just get the table structure from the cloud DB, recreate it on the localhost, export data from cloud DB as excel file and import the excel file using load data infile into the table on the localhost.

Another way you could do this is with a DB client like Navicat where you have both DBs connected as hosts.  It allows for seamless migration of data. You can get a free 30 day trial [Here](http://www.navicat.com/). You can drag and drop tables from one connected host to the other.

You could also try this using either a scripting language such as python or php by connecting to cloud DB, grapping data from there and then connect to local DB and insert the data on localhost.